# Extract files from traffic captured with WireShark

Tags: wifi, wireshark

Is there a way to extract image, video files from WireShark capture files? Is there a tool to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do any of [these tools](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Tools) do what you're looking for?

What about [foremost](http://packetlife.net/blog/2009/jul/13/quick-packet-capture-data-extraction/)?

Comment: I know these. I think only ProConvert does what I want but suppose that it is no longer maintained.

Comment: Edited with second link...